# Can't get results from RXJava subscribe

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java3

I'm new to RXJava.
I have this code

```
Observable.just(
    getAllImagesFromFirebaseStorage(
                                    spotsList.get(i).getName(),
                                    spotsList.get(i).getZones().get(j).getZoneImage(),
                                    outputStream
                                )
)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(item -> {
    Log.i("test", "inside subscribe rxjava");
    linearProgressIndicator.setProgressCompat(item, true);
}).dispose();
```

I'm calling the method `getAllImagesFromFirebaseStorage` that downloads images from firebase and stores them in internal memory, but it freezes the UI so I'm trying to implement RXJava so that the method can be performed in a secondary thread.

`getAllImagesFromFirebaseStorage` returns an Integer which should be updating the `linearProgressIndicator`

I've been watching tutorials on implementing RXJava but it doesn't seem to work for me because it enters in the `.subscribe` part of the code immediately and `item` is always zero.

I understand that on `.subscribe` I'm getting the response of the method I'm calling on the secondary thread, is that so?

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two things are wrong.

1. `Observable.just` signals a constant value that has been created before RxJava is even involved. Pretty much, `getAllImagesFromFirebaseStorage` runs before you even create a flow. This is a common beginner mistake.

You want to trigger computation when a subscription happens, not before that. Use `fromCallable`:

```java
Observable.fromCallable(() ->
    getAllImagesFromFirebaseStorage(
                                    spotsList.get(i).getName(),
                                    spotsList.get(i).getZones().get(j).getZoneImage(),
                                    outputStream
                                )
)
```

2. You call `dispose` on the created sequence right after you subscribe, which will immediately cancel all computation and emission. Just don't call it.

Comment: Hi Akarnokd, I applied the changes you suggested but, when I'm inside 'subscribe' and printing 'item, it is always zero. The method 'getAllImagesFromFirebaseStorage' is returning an integer and with that the progress indicator should update but always returns zero. What could it be?

Comment: Can't tell without knowing what your method does. It just returns one value so if that value does not depend on its inputs or external factors, you get the same value every time.